# Why doesn't the make clean function work on vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile

```bash
    CC = gcc
    CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic
    OBJ = bounds.o powers.o
    EXEC = myProgram

    $(EXEC) : $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(OBJ) -o $(EXEC)

    ifdef DEBUG
        CFLAGS += -D DEBUG
        DEBUG : clean $(EXEC)
    endif

    bounds.o : bounds.c macros.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) bounds.c -c

    powers.o : powers.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) powers.c -c

    clean :
        rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJ)
```

When I type `make clean` in a terminal this comes up:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -f myProgram 
bounds.o powers.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:21: clean] Error 2
```

I typed `make` before as well, so the object files are there. The object files are also in the same directory as the makefile. And I can remove those object files by typing `rm bounds.o` in a terminal. However my `make clean` command doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: Are you on Windows? ```rm``` is Linux, you would need to run ```del``` instead if you are. I pretty much exclusively develop on Linux, so i don't know the del syntax really.

Comment: Based on the error messages, the OP is definitely on Windows. But it is possible to have the `rm` command on Windows, and the OP already expressly specifies that they *do* have a working `rm` command.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75705089/2402272

Comment: @JohnBollinger OP only expresses that when they open a terminal it works. they may be building and trying the command in different terminals. How are you concluding that they are using the same for both?

Comment: I don't have to be sure of that.  This answer presumes that `rm` is not available to the OP, but the OP has already plausibly claimed otherwise.  I'm not sure that enough information has been provided to write an answer, but why the OP can run a `rm` command from the command line but not indirectly from `make` is one of the key things for an answer to cover -- perhaps *the* key thing to cover.

Comment: As John says, "in a terminal" is not very useful when it comes to Windows.  There are at least three possibilities for "in a terminal" and they all have different behaviors: you could be in a `cmd.exe`, in a Powershell terminal, or in a POSIX terminal like Git Bash.  GNU Make is using `cmd.exe` (it does not just use whatever shell you were using when you invoked `make`) so saying it works to run `rm` in some other terminal, is not informative.

Comment: my rm command works and I'm on windows